# How to use tabulate in the tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to convert that old piece of code to tidyverse. Can somebody help?

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(sex),function(x) tabulate(x[,1],nbins=5))

# result
#     sex V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1 female  1  6  0  2  0
#2   male  2 11  3  0  0

dat <- structure(list(P1 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# set number of bins
nb = 5

dat %>%
  count(P1, sex) %>%                                # count combinations
  complete(P1 = 1:nb, sex, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%  # if a bin is missing add a zero count
  spread(P1, n, sep = "_")                          # reshape dataset

# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#   sex     P1_1  P1_2  P1_3  P1_4  P1_5
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 female     1     6     0     2     0
# 2 male       2    11     3     0     0
```

Comment: the 'retired' spread() can be replaced with: pivot_wider(names_from = P1, values_from = n, names_prefix = "P1_")

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do with `table` after converting the 'P1' column to `factor`

```
table(transform(dat, P1 = factor(P1, levels = 1:5,
             labels = paste0("P1_", 1:5)))[2:1])
#       P1
#sex      P1_1 P1_2 P1_3 P1_4 P1_5
#  female    1    6    0    2    0
#  male      2   11    3    0    0
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), sex ~ factor(P1, levels = 1:5,
         labels = paste0("P1_", 1:5)), drop = FALSE, length)
#      sex P1_1 P1_2 P1_3 P1_4 P1_5
#1: female    1    6    0    2    0
#2:   male    2   11    3    0    0
```